How to test an Angular method with an RxJS subscription that awaits on multiple methods
I'm trying to test an Angular service. Another service provides an observable to which this service needs to react, start some parallel HTTP requests and do something with them.
I'm struggling to test them.
Here is a working dummy test of exactly what I'm trying to achieve:
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpTestingController, provideHttpClientTesting } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { fakeAsync, flush, flushMicrotasks, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { createSpyFromClass, Spy } from 'jest-auto-spies';
import { firstValueFrom, Subject, Subscription, tap } from 'rxjs';

describe('Testings tests', () => {
  let httpTestingController!: HttpTestingController;
  let someSourceOfDataMock: Spy<SomeSourceOfData>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SomeSourceOfData,
          useValue: createSpyFromClass(SomeSourceOfData, { observablePropsToSpyOn: ['latestInfo'] }),
        },
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideHttpClientTesting(),
        DummyTest,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    someSourceOfDataMock = TestBed.inject<any>(SomeSourceOfData);
  });

  it('Should request data', fakeAsync(() => {
    //Arrange
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    let dummyTest = TestBed.inject(DummyTest);

    //Act
    someSourceOfDataMock.latestInfo.nextWith('go go go');
    flushMicrotasks();

    //Assert
    const request = httpTestingController.expectOne('https://google.com');
    expect(request.request.method).toBe('GET');
    request.flush({});
    const requestTwo = httpTestingController.expectOne('https://yahoo.com');
    expect(requestTwo.request.method).toBe('GET');
    requestTwo.flush({});
    httpTestingController.verify();
    dummyTest.Dispose();
  }));
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DummyTest {
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    someSourceOfData: SomeSourceOfData
  ) {
    this.subscription = someSourceOfData.latestInfo
      .pipe(tap(info => console.log('pipe: data received', info)))
      .subscribe(async info => {
        //Important, if I don't call this line, everything is working
        await this.DoSomething();
        console.log('subscription: info received', info);
        await this.TestRequest();
      });
  }
  public Dispose() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  private async TestRequest() {
    console.log('Refreshing request');
    await Promise.all([
      firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<string>('https://google.com')),
      firstValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<string>('https://yahoo.com')),
    ]);
    //....
  }

  private async DoSomething() {
    //In my real case, I do retrieve some data from another observable
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));
  }
}

export class SomeSourceOfData {
  private _dataSource = new Subject<string>();
  public latestInfo = this._dataSource.asObservable();
}

My current issue is that the Pipe: data received is reached, but not the subscription: info received (and obviously, the TestRequest method is not called, and therefore, the test fails).
I tried to use fakeasync+flush to ensure the micro-tasks were executed, but I get the same result. I also tried to use tick.
If in the subscribe of the DummyTest I don't call DoSomething, it does succeed. Like if the flushMicroTasks only flushes the currently awaiting one but not the one that might arrive just after this one.
The actual code that uses this does work.
